# Является ли несколько файлов pom.xml в проекте критерием микросервисной архитектуры?

Tags: java, spring, maven, микросервисы

Открыл рабочий проект компании. А там - файлы **`pom.xml`** лежат. Один - в корне проекта. Ещё несколько - в подпапках.

**Вопрос:** правильно ли я понимаю, что микросервисная архитектура подразумевает каждый сервис -> одна папка -> наличие хотя бы одного **`pom.xml`.**? Если нет, то о чём в принципе говорит наличие нескольких pom.xml в одном проекте на спринге?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если в проекте несколько pom.xml файлов, то однозначно можно сказать только, что проект разбит на несколько модулей.

Эти модули могут быть:

1. просто библиотеками используемыми в монолите
2. отдельными утилитами (например, отдельная программа для генерации тестовых данных)
3. микросервисами.

Однозначно сказать нельзя не посмотрев, что они собой представляют и как взаимодействуют.

> правильно ли я понимаю, что микросервисная архитектура подразумевает каждый сервис -> одна папка -> наличие хотя бы одного pom.xml

Одной из важных характеристик микросервиса, является возможность его независимой эволюции. То есть возможность внести в него изменения не затронув остальных сервисов. Это подразумевает определенную степень изоляции микросервисов, которую гораздо легче достичь, если микросервисы разделены физически, как в процессе их работы так и в коде. И это обычно означает, что каждый каждый сервис выделен как минимум в отдельный мавен модуль, а часто и в отдельный репозиторий системы контроля версий.

Но мавен очень гибкий и позволяет создавать несколько рабочих приложений из одного модуля (т.е. иметь один pom.xml, но при этом все равно несколько сервисов). Это снимает искусственны барьеры, которые помагают изолировать сервисы, и кое-кто может даже сказать, что это делает такую архитектуру не микросервисной.

Тут нужно заметить, что микросервисная архитектура - это расплывчатое понятие. Есть спектр возможностей. На одном краю монолит, на другом краю - архитектура со всеми лучшими практиками по созданию микросервисов. Но есть и много промежуточных форм. И где на этом спектре "уже начинаются микросервисы" - вопрос дискуссионный.

Comment: Очень информативно. В общем-то ответ аналогичен предыдущему и дополняет его.

Answer (score 4):

Не ну подумайте как может pom файл влиять на архитектуру. Вы думаете что если он один то архитектура не может быть микросервисной? Перефразируйте вопрос. Чтоб на него можно было ответить.

> Является ли несколько файлов pom.xml в проекте критерием
> микросервисной архитектуры? - *Ответ, нет не является.*

Архитектура может быть микросервисной, а каждый сервис может не знать о существовании кого либо чего. Соответственно сервис даже самый маленький будучи частью приложения может не иметь вовсе pom xml необходимый для maven.

Apache Maven — фреймворк для автоматизации сборки проектов на основе описания их структуры в файлах на языке POM. Несколько малениких пакетов с pom файлами могут собраться в один монолит. Посмотрите примеры с использованием пакетов к примеру core, in, out.

**Update.**

У вас основное препятствие в понимании архитектуры.

> Архитектура программной системы — это форма, которая придается системе
> ее создателями. Эта форма образуется делением системы на компоненты,
> их организацией и определением способов взаимодействий между ними.

Монолитное приложение представляет собой приложение, доставляемое через единое **развертывание**. - *Соответственно если вы разворачиваете своё приложение в через множественнное развертывание это не есть монолит.*

Теперь поговорим о pom и прочих деталей.

> Любую программную систему можно разложить на два основных элемента
> : политику и детали. Политика воплощает все бизнес-правила и
> процедуры. Политика — вот истинная ценность системы.
>
> Детали — это все остальное, что позволяет людям, другим системам и
> программистам взаимодействовать с политикой, никак не влияя на ее
> поведение. К ним можно отнести устройства ввода/вывода, базы данных,
> веб-системы, серверы, фреймворки, протоколы обмена данными и т. д.
>
> Цель архитектора — создать такую форму для системы, которая сделает
> политику самым важным элементом, а детали — не относящимися к
> политике. Это позволит откладывать и задерживать принятие решений о
> деталях.

(Мартин Р.
М29 Чистая архитектура. Искусство разработки программного обеспечения. —
СПб.: Питер, 2018. — 352 с.: ил. — (Серия «Библиотека программиста»))

Comment: Спасибо. А если перефразировать вопрос - может ли быть архитектура монолит, и содержать в себе несколько pom.xml? (Причем каждый рабочий, если его убираем - то проект (какая либо его часть) грохается.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin Да прочитайте последнии предложения

Comment: Спасибо. Если не будет других мнений, к вечеру ответ принят.