# Декомпозировать на микросервисы

Tags: база-данных, архитектура, ddd, микросервисы

вопрос теоретический про предметную область. Читаю книгу Криса Ричардсона и в ней есть всё что нужно знать для разработки и вот такая картинка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас у меня такая доменная модель:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Следует ли мне разбить это на новые сервисы Consumer, Order, Kitchen? Если да, то возникают проблемы при построении других сервисов с такими же названиями, но для другой цели.

Насколько верны мои мысли про то, что это будет другое приложение в отдельном пакете?Например сейчас у меня всё в директории backend.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меня взгляд со стороны - методологический, так как о микросервисах знаю крайне мало. Смущает, что у вас уже есть доменная модель, вероятно, созданная для каких-то целей, и тут, не говоря зачем, вы собираетесь: a) её разбивать на новые сервисы, да б) ещё с дублирующимися именами. Любые изменения должны преследовать какую-то цель, любые возможности уменьшить ясность должны блокироваться. Да и будет ли это приложение в отдельном пакете или нет - вам лучше знать. Если выгод от приложений в едином пакете нет, то лучше разбить. Если есть, надо анализировать + и -. Игнорируйте коммент, если что:-)

Comment: Обычно микросервис это не просто отдельный пакет, это будет как минимум отдельный модуль мавен в многомодульном проекте. Или вообще отдельный проект. Смотрите тут я писал об этом https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1282842/218971 То что сервисы будут называться одинаково - не проблема. В каждом под домене свои сущности и сервисы и имена вполне себе могут дублироваться.

Comment: Следует ли разбивать - на это нельзя сказать ничего однозначно. Какая цель? Можно точно тот же функционал и в монолите сделать. Так что разбивать или нет - это все довольно условно и по желанию. Главное, что если уж разбивать, то правильно - т.е. по границам bounded context-ов. А они определяются предметной областью и требованиями, коих я тут не знаю.

Comment: Примеры в книгах максимально упрощенные, примеры реальной модели микросервисов просто умножит объем книги в разы. Потому, если у вас 6 классов в приложении, то вам не нужны микросервисы вообще.